# App launch got stuck with black screen. This happens sporadically. Most of the time launching gracefully without any issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Sometime iOS app is getting stuck with black screen while launching the app. Most of the time it's launching gracefully without any issue.

This legacy app in the market more than 5Yrs we never encountered any issue in the past related to app launch.

Comment: Show didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are performing some UI work on a non-main thread.  Put breakpoints into your network callbacks or any other callback your launch sequence may be using. Hint: you can put a Thread.isMainThread==false conditions to your breakpoints.